# Common stack for some public variables

Tags: c#, heap-memory, stack-memory

Someone in stack-overflow answered "stack is attached to a thread, so when the thread exits the stack is reclaimed." But what about public variables how they are managed once thread execution is completed.

For Ex. Declared public variable like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        int k = 10;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            k = k + 5;
        }
}
```

So in this whenever we click button1 a thread is created which updates value of k and then exist so as per this statement stack should be reclaimed and recent value of k should be lost but in reality it store that value and next button click will changes its retain value for ex. from 1) 10 to 15 2)15 to 20 3) 20 to 25 etc....

So My question is where such global variables are stored. Whether any other stack used for global variables.  Also I will use object of a class inside a function for ex. such as

```
public function add (int a, int b)
{
       int c; 
       clsitem objitem = new clsitem();
       c=a+b + objitem.id;
       retun c;
}
```

so what will happened of objitem , whether it will store in stack and reclaimed when thread exits or it will stay in heap as it is an object

Comment: What makes you think that clicking on the button creates a thread?

Comment: Button click will start execution of program again, so I guess we can call it as thread

Comment: @Ashish Khandelwal No. *One can't call it that* and be correct. A [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) is a specific concept.

Comment: what about system.threading namespace in which we can create new thread. I guess we can create thread and operating system will allocate its cpu time for that

Comment: Dear Jon it can be silly question from me but still expecting some good answer from you which will clear my doubts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example here, k is not a stack-based variable - it's a field of the Form1 class and is hence stored with the instance of the form.

The two arguments to button1_click are examples of stack-based variables.

Comment: so is it means that k will be stored in heap

Comment: Yes - along with the other (implicit) fields of the Form class.